# Create Calendar with backbone

Tags: backbone.js, calendar

I need ideas or directions to create calendar in backbone.js Has anyone already do this or has ideas how to do this like in Android Calendar

I am interested in this week view so I could display Events. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I have a Backbone App that has a calendar and I use [FullCalendar jQuery plugin](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/) to show and create the events. When fetching I translate from my collection to the format expected by the plugin and vice versa.

Once you got it running it is very nice and easy to use. The documentation is also good.